# How to run a Django Project on a Personal Run Server

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, server, virtual-machine

I've been wanting to run my own server for a while and I figured that running one for my **django website** would be a good start. What do you recommend I use for this? I've been trying to use a **Ubuntu Virtual Machine** to run it on one of my old laptops that I don't really use anymore until I can buy a dedicated server.

Should I run it from a **Virtual Machine**? If so, would **Ubuntu** be best? That appears to be the case, but I want to be sure before I invest in anything. I want to be able to access the website from other computers, just like any other website. Am I going about this wrong? If so, what can you suggest me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need a static IP address.

If this is your first experiment, my advice would be:

1) Use an old, dedicated PC with no other stuff on it.  Unless you do it just right, you should presume hackers could get anything on the disk...

2) Why make life complex with layer after layer of software?  Install Ubuntu and run a standard server under a Unix OS

3) Be very careful about the rest of your attached network.  Even if the PC is dedicated, unless you properly managed port forwarding, etc., ALL of your computers could be susceptible to attack.

An old friend of mine discovered, back in the Napster peer-to-peer days, that he could basically go and read EVERYTHING on the hard drives of most people who had set up Napster on their computer.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your requirements. Will you be accessing the website externally (making it public) or locally? Running Django from your laptop can work but if you are planning to make it public, you will need an external IP to point your domain to. Unless you have a business account, ISPs usually don't give static IPs to individual customers. Ubuntu would be a wise choice and you can run conda or virtualenv easily.

VPS are quite cheap these days. You can look into AWS free tier that provides you with 500 hours/month on a micro server.

If you are planning to access your website internally then you don't need anything other than your laptop or perhaps raspberry pi. If you are trying to make it available for everyone on the external network, VPS would be the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, and this changes often, I like to either setup a local development environment using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) (to install dependencies) and [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) (to expose machine to an external address) or [C9.io](https://c9.io). If you want further info about setup, I'm happy to provide.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated Ubantu is a good choice but there is also Debian. I use Debian because I started off working with a colleague who was already using it and I find it very good.  I began with an old, disused desktop PC which I nuked and turned into a proper linux server. For development I didn't need a very high spec machine. (Think it has 1 GB ram)  I have it set up in my flat and my domestic internet connection is fine for most of my needs. Note:  It isn't necessary to have a static IP address for development, although it is preferable if you already have one.  As an alternative you can use a service such as dnydns.org where you can set up virtual domain names that point to your domestic dynamic IP address.  Most routers these days have facilities within them for updating services like dyndns.org with your new dynamic IP address or you can install a plug-in to your server that will do this for you.  All my projects have their own virtualenvs and I have VNCServer installed so I can access my server and work from anywhere where I have an internet connection.  I've been running this way for the past three years with some household name clients and haven't had any issues at all. 
When it comes to production you can simply use any of the many VPS services that are out there. Amazon has already been mentioned. Someone recommended creating a droplet at DigitalOcean.com as I was wanting to host django applications and I find them to be very good and cost effective.  Anyway just my 2 cents worth...hope it helps